# How do you determine the capabilities of a WebCam?

Tags: usb, devices, camera

I have a collection of WebCam's lying around.  Some of them are new, some go back a decade -- have to love not having to "upgrade" devices in Linux!

Somehow I've developed the impression that manufacturers come up with different ways to convince consumers that this year's product is different from last year's (repeat ad-absurdium).

What I would like to know is - how can I tell what each of these devices are actually capable of?

I've run `lsusb -v -d` ...  By the look of it, I could probably `grep` the information that I need out of the copious information that results.  Is there an easier way?  I'm thinking of something like `xrandr` which, when run without arguments, dumps the capabilities of the various output devices available.

Comment: `v4l-info` is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Also: `v4l2-ctl --all` will tell you a pile of stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of tools you can use:

```
v4l2-ctl --all
```

That's probably the most useful, if you want more info on the formats use:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools,  one is v4l2-ctl, definitely on ubuntu and linux, read more [here](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/V4l2-ctl)
List camera device devices:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

List supported video formats and resolutions of default video device /dev/video0:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
```

List supported video formats and resolutions of a specific video device:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video0
```

Get all details of a video device:

```
v4l2-ctl --all --device /dev/video0
```